# Is there any way to create array or array of object like this?

Tags: javascript

This is  where i had fetch multiple GET URLs at once and then put the fetched JSON data

```
   Promise.all([
     fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/chartTable').then((response) => response.json()),
     fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/chartTable1').then((response) => response.json()),
  ]).then(function (response) {
    console.log(...response.map((res) => res['userDetails']));
  });
```

and when i do console.log(...response.map((res) => res['userDetails'])); .Data will come like this in Inscpect

```
            (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
             0 : {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill": 12 , "knock": 1}, 
             1 : {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 12 , "knock": 4},
             2 :{"id": 3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 8 , "knock": 4}

          (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
                  {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill":12  , "knock": 4}, 
                 {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 13 , "knock": 3},
                 {"id":3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 5 , "knock": 1}
```

but i want to convert this like this

```
     "key1": [{"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill": 12 , "knock": 1}, 
                   {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 12 , "knock": 4},
                   {"id": 3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 8 , "knock": 4}],

    "key2": [
                 {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill":12  , "knock": 4}, 
                 {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 13 , "knock": 3},
                 {"id":3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 5 , "knock": 1}]
```

When i create variable and create demo. console.log(res).It error say Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

```
 var demo=[{key1: response[0].userDetails, key2: response[1].userDetails}];
 var res = demo.key1.map(function(item, idx) {
            return Object.keys(item).reduce(function(obj, key) {
                if (key == 'name') {
                    obj[key] = item[key]
                } else {
                    obj[key] = item[key] + demo.key2[idx][key];
                }
                return obj;
            }, {});
        });
        console.log(res)
```

Comment: `console.log(...response.map((res, i) => ({[\`${key}${i+1}\`]: res['userDetails']})));`

Comment: @JaromandaX  error is like  key is not defined

Comment: I messsed up - should've been `[\`key${i+1}\`]`

Comment: So, just `console.log({key1: response[0].userDetails, key2: response[1].userDetails})`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks
but i need to put in variable so 
var demo=[ ...response.map((res, i) => ({[`key${i+1}`]: res['salesTable']}))]
can i write this way ?

Comment: what's salesTables? it's userDetails in the code you've shown

Comment: Sorry
but your solution worked .thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array to the values of the object and flatten it:

```
// if you have this
var array = [{ 0 : {"id": 1, "name": "Robbie", "kill": 12 , "knock": 1}}, 
             { 1 : {"id": 2, "name": "Mohamand", "kill": 12 , "knock": 4}},
             {2 :{"id": 3, "name": "Jebisha", "kill": 8 , "knock": 4}}]

var array2 = array.map(item => Object.values(item)).flat()
console.log(array2)  
/*
Will print
[{
  id: 1,
  kill: 12,
  knock: 1,
  name: "Robbie"
}, {
  id: 2,
  kill: 12,
  knock: 4,
  name: "Mohamand"
}, {
  id: 3,
  kill: 8,
  knock: 4,
  name: "Jebisha"
}]
*/
```